# Listing all products and check if they are already in your favorite or not in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have the following 3 Schema in MongoDB

```js
1. const FavoriteSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    },
    product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product',
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true })


2. const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: -1
    }
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    }
})

ProductSchema.virtual('favorites', {
    ref: 'favorite',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'product'
})


3. const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String
    }
})

UserSchema.virtual('products', {
    ref: 'product',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user_id'
})

UserSchema.virtual('favorites', {
    ref: 'favorite',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user'
})
```

lets say there many products and I want to show the list of products and also whether the product is in the user's favorite list or not.

So I do like :

```
ProductCollection.find().populate('user').populate('favorites')
```

I get only the list of products and user info of the product but not the favorite.
I dont know why?